# Angular - function inside a Public method to call to a button

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, function

I have public method, where i need to create a function to call to button.
For example

```
public loadDataDateComparison(objLimits?:any) {
          function minMax() {
            //sorting the data min-max
            data.data.sort(function(a, b) {
              return a[1] - b[1]
            })
          }
}
```

And i have to call the function minMax to button in html

```
<button (click)="minMax()">Hello World</button>
```

It's not working

Answer (score 0):

you can't call minMax from template as it exists only within scope created by loadDataDateComparison method

```js
public loadDataDateComparison(objLimits?:any) {
          function minMax() {
            //sorting the data min-max
            data.data.sort(function(a, b) {
              return a[1] - b[1]
            })
          }
          
          minMax();
}
```

```html
<button (click)="loadDataDateComparison()">Hello World</button>
```

Comment: But what if, the loadDataDateComparison does something else, and i just want to get that part of the code the minMax function from it

Comment: in that case you can create public minMax method

and call it from template and loadDataDateComparison